# Form Processing: using cleaned_data

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make a BMI calculator for my program using Django  Web Frameworks:

This my views.py

```
def bmi(h,w):
    return(w*10000.00/(h*h)

def bmi_view(request):
    form=Bmi_forms()
    if request.method=='POST':

    form=Bmi_forms(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid:
         weight=form.cleaned_data['weight']
         height=form.cleaned_data['height']
         Bmi_value =bmi(height,weight)
         form.save()

context={'form':form,'Bmi_value': Bmi_value}

return render(request,'Bmidisplay.html',context)
```

This gives a invalid Syntax Error ,I don't know what to do
Some of my doubts are:
 1. How can I modify my views to calculate BMI( I feel there is conflict in saving the forms data and calculation)
 2. How to display the calculated Displayed Bmi value in a Template ie HTML file and give conditions like

```
a)If BMI <18.5 ==Overweight

b)If BMI between 18.5 and 25 =Normal Weight

c)If BMI above 25 =Overweight
```

Thats all,I am quite new to Python Django please Help me as I am quite new to this Language.It would be highly appreciate if you write the suitable code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check indents in your code. Code after `if request.method=='POST':` should be indented too. Secondly you forgot closing bracket here: `return(w*10000.00/(h*h))`. Finally this should be `if form.is_valid():` not `if form.is_valid:`, [is_valid()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) is callable.

As for your question about conditions in template, use [if](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#if) tag:

```
{% if Bmi_value > 25 or Bmi_value < 18.5 %}
  Overweight
{% else %}
  Normal Weight
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Silly mistakes Kill me at the end